# Signing data in Android and Verifying it in python

Tags: java, android, python, digital-signature

I have written the following code to Sign data in android:

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try{
        String m ="This is my message";
        System.out.println(m);

        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGen.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey priKey = kp.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pubKey = kp.getPublic();


        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(pubKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);

        System.out.println("WITH toString: ");
        System.out.println("Mod :" + publicKeySpec.getModulus().toString());
        System.out.println("Exp :" + publicKeySpec.getPublicExponent().toString());
        System.out.println("PublicKey:" + pubKey.toString());




        System.out.println("PublicKey:" + pubKey);
        System.out.println("PublicKey Base64:" +MyBase64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded()));

        Signature instance = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        instance.initSign(priKey);
        instance.update(m.getBytes());
        byte[] signature = instance.sign();
        System.out.println("Signature: " + MyBase64.encode(signature));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I am copy pasting values from adb logcat into python and I am verifying it in python using:

```
mod=#I paste mod here
exp=#I paste exp here
signature=#I paste signature here

message="This is my message"

publicKey = RSA.construct((mod,exp))
print 'PublicKey Base64: ' + publicKey.exportKey()
print str(publicKey)
test = SHA.new(message)
verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(publicKey)
signature_base = base64.b64decode(signature)
print "Verification: " + str(verifier.verify(test, signature_base))
```

I find that MyBase64.encode(pubKey.getEncoded()) (in java) is same as publicKey.exportKey() (in python)

However, the verification always results to false.

The java code seems to work fine , if I run it using javac .

Any help, what may be going wrong?

Comment: By the way, the scheme you've implemented has little in common with digital signatures because you don't use any certificates. Just hashing your data (with SHA-1 or other algoritmh) will provide EXACTLY the same guarantees as you get with the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Often an error like this has to do with extra whitespace sneaking into the data string.  Try stripping it before computing the hashes.

Comment: I have tried printing the size of the mod , exp and signature they are same.